# currentStyle in IE is null

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to caculate the current style of an element:

```
function cssIsLoaded(c) {
    if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        return window.getComputedStyle(c, null).display === "none";
    }
    else if (c.currentStyle) {

    }

    return true;
}

(function() {
    var cssload = document.createElement("div");
    cssload.className = "_css_loaded";
    checkLoaded();

    function checkLoaded() {
        if (!cssIsLoaded(cssload)) setTimeout(function() {
            checkLoaded();
        }, 20);
        else blalbalblbalbalablbal();
    }
})();
```

IE doesnt get into the 2nd condition, `c.currentStyle` is null... why is that?

Comment: Where are you calling `cssIsLoaded()`? What element are you passing? Can you create an example at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I am passing a DIV I just created. i call the function once its JS is loaded in <head> in the site. (it is called right after i created that DIV

Comment: please show exactly how you are passing it. That is most likely where the error is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An element doesn't get its `currentStyle` property populated until it's added to the document, which makes some sense: until the element's been added to the document, the browser cannot know which existing style rules will apply to it.